# Dragging a chrome tab out in to a separate window erases the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I'm working on a drawing webapp and I noticed that if you use it in Chrome and drag the tab out out of the tab bar and in to a separate window, it erases the canvas until you switch to another tab and back.

Is there any way to detect this if it happens and if so, refresh the canvas so the user doesn't have to switch to another tab and back? Because they probably wouldn't know to do that.

I googled for random canvas jsFiddles and found one that does it (they don't all do it): http://jsfiddle.net/jimrhoskins/Sv87G/

I'm using Chrome 51 and if you have that open in a tab and drag the tab out to a separate window, it'll blank out the canvas until you switch to another tab and back.

```
.
```

Weird bug. Anyone know why this is happening or how to resolve it?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error on Chrome 51 on OS X 10.11. What OS are you on? Have you tried disabling extensions?

Comment: @AppleCrazy: I'm on Windows 7. It still happens with all extensions disabled.

Comment: happens on Windows 10 - Chrome 51.

Comment: This is most likely a GPU related problem. You can keep a copy of the canvas as pixel data, but you will have to find out how to detect the drag to the new window, or you can just create a copy every time there is a change to the canvas.

Comment: Try listening to window resize events. Redraw if triggered.